# CSS3 support in mobile browsers

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry, mobile, css

What, if any, support is there for CSS3 in mobile browsers? The specific browsers I'm curious about are the ones used in the iPhone, Android, and Blackberry phones. Any links to relevant resources would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i hope this link is an updated link and help you for further updates http://caniuse.com/#agents=mobile&cats=CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both iPhone and Android systems use WebKit as the rendering engine in their mobile browsers. I believe Blackberry are moving to Webkit as well at some point. This engine has some of the best support for parts of CSS 3 available at the moment, as well as quite a lot of proprietary extensions.

I would recommend researching what is available in WebKit, and then testing.

A great resource for support tables is http://www.quirksmode.org where PPK is doing more and more mobile browser testing to answer just these kind of questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [acid3.acidtests.org](http://acid3.acidtests.org) and h[ttp://www.css3.info/selectors-test/test.html](http://www.css3.info/selectors-test/test.html) on the respective browsers to check some compatibility, but that may not be an exact determining factor of full compatibility.  However I don't think any of the mobile browsers currently fully support CSS3.

Comment: That url (acid3.acidtests.org) scores 100/100 on the current iPhone browser.  I'd be surprised if Android scored any differently, also being Webkit based.  However there are a few small visual glitches on the left side, when compared to the reference rendering.

Comment: On Android 2.1 it scores 92/100 and is pretty identical to the example (Scores 43/43 on the selector test).  I read an article today about RIM moving Blackberry's to the open webkit and showed a video of the browser scoring 100/100.

Answer (score 1):

a do quirksmode.org specifically this page: http://www.quirksmode.org/webkit.html

Answer (score 1):

In the BlackBerry Documentation for Developers, there is a documentation for the [BlackBerry Browser](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=BlackBerry+Browser), including [CSS Reference - BlackBerry Browser](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11845/BlackBerry_Browser-CSS_Reference--624406-1104011351-001-US.pdf).  There is no specific mention of CSS3, but that document lists supported CSS properties.

There is also a [BlackBerry Widget web standards support](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/14028/BB_Browser_content_support_by_version_438586_11.jsp) page that states 4.7.1 and 5.0 have partial support for CSS 3 color and full support for CSS 3 marquee, CSS 3 media queries, CSS 3 namespaces and CSS 3 selectors.

Answer (score 0):

well when i mind internet i found usefull source to you i hope it will help you more [excellent description on mobile browser compatablity](http://caniuse.com/#agents=mobile&cats=CSS)